# Why don't the export and unset commands have a path?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

As far as I've been able to tell, just about every command line utility has a path pointing to their binary.

For example, `$ which which` returns `/usr/bin/which` and `$ which env` returns `/usr/bin/env`.

But `$ which export` and `$ which unset` both return nothing and produce an exit code of `1` instead of `0`. What's different about `export` and `unset` that they don't have a path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: Builtins are built in Bash, so they are not external binary files (and hence they don't have a path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export` and `unset` are *built in* to the shell (other examples are `cd` and `alias`). They aren't separate binaries and don't exist as separate entities.

`man builtins` will give you more info.

Comment: A lot of the commands listed by `man builtins` do exist, because Bash has them built in but there is a separate copy on your computer. The builtins `alias`, `cd`, `export`, `unset`, `shopt`, etc. are special because they *cannot* be implemented by external programs.